# Different initial scene based on some logic in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Is it possible to set different initial scenes based on some asynchronous logic in react-native-router-flux?
What i'm actually trying to do is show a different scene (let's say a login page) the first time the app is run. I determine first run by storing some value in an sqlite database locally.

My current implementation is to set a 'dummy' component as the initial scene, from within which i can perform the database logic, and subsequently redirect to the appropriate scene. While it works i strongly feel there has to be a better way.

Thanks.

```
//currenlty, App.js looks something like this:

//imports here  

//app starting point, imported into index.ios.js and index.android.js
export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        const store = createStore(allReducers, {});

        return (
            <Provider store={store} >
                <Router>
                    <Scene key="dummy" component={Dummy} />
                    <Scene key="login" component={Login} />
                    <Scene key="main" component={Main} />
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
    }

}



And dummy component something like this:


//imports here

class Dummy extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        const initService = new InitService();

        //some asyn func that checks local db to determine if this is the first time running
        initService.hasRunBefore()
            .then(value => {
                if (value === true) {
                    Actions.main({ type: 'replace' });
                }
                else {
                    Actions.login({ type: 'replace' });
                }
            }
            );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View />
        );
    }
}

export default Dummy;
```

Comment: at the time of routing scene check there if user logged in then change router id that will take another scene.

Comment: How i do i hook into the routing action to redirect? I can't seem to find anything like that in the documentation?

Comment: add you code here